# How to add exponential trend line to a semi logarithmic scatter plot in ArcPy?

Tags: python, charts, scatter-plot, arcgis, arcpy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t61Nf.png)**I want to create a semi-logarithmic scatter plot and add an exponential trend line to the graph. I would also like to limit the x and y (log y) axes extent with their highest value. Also want to define the interval of the x and y axes.
I have tried with the following code**

```
[enter image description here][1]>>> import numpy as np
... import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
... fc='Yearwise'
... x= \[r\[0\] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,'Year') if not r \[0\] is None\]
... y= \[r\[0\] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,'SMI') if not r \[0\] is None\]
... ylog= np.log(y)
... plt.yscale('log') 
... plt.ylim(\[0.1,10000\]) 
... plt.scatter(x, ylog) 
... curve_fit= np.polyfit(x,ylog,1) 
... plt.show() 
... print(curve_fit)][1]][1]
```

But have got the attached result.

Comment: Please make sure you've correctly added the result, it is currently not visible.

Comment: Please find the image (enter image description here) [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t61Nf.png @YashvanderBamel